# It submits the form automatically, but it wont stop reloading repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery

The page won't stop reloading. How can I stop it?

```
$(function() {
    var canSubmit = localStorage.getItem("can_submit");
    if(!canSubmit) {
        document.forms['myForm'].submit();
        localStorage.setItem("can_submit","1");
        window.location.reload();
    }
    localStorage.removeItem("can_submit");
});
```

Comment: how about else condition for the `removeItem` @Joe

Comment: @DavidJorHpan i'll try it

Comment: @DavidJorHpan I love you men thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a form reloads the page, and stops the rest of the Javascript. You should update the local storage *before* you submit. And there's no point in calling `window.location.reload()`, because submitting a form reloads it with what the form returns.

```
$(function() {
    var canSubmit = localStorage.getItem("can_submit");
    if(!canSubmit) {
        localStorage.setItem("can_submit","1");
        document.forms['myForm'].submit();
    }
    localStorage.removeItem("can_submit");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
var canSubmit = localStorage.getItem("can_submit");
if(!canSubmit) {
    localStorage.setItem("can_submit","1");
    document.forms['myForm'].submit();
}else{
localStorage.removeItem("can_submit");
 }});
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This work for me without reloading and redirecting to action page

```
$("#myForm").submit(function () {
                var nameValue = $('#Name').val();
                var emailValue = $('#Email').val();
                var phoneValue = $('#Phone').val();
                var subjectValue = $('#Subject').val();
                var messageValue = $('#Message').val();
                $.post('YourActionUrl', { Name: nameValue, Email: emailValue, Phone: phoneValue, Subject: subjectValue, Message: messageValue }, function (data) {

                });

                $("#myForm")[0].reset();
                // make sure you return false to cancel any default actions of this button
                return false;

            });
```